# How to get div to automatically scroll down when height increases?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have an autocomplete. When the dropdown appears, it may go out of view because it is close to the bottom.

The height of the div that contains this dropdown is increases. However, it does not automatically scroll to the end.

How to get it to scroll to the end?

Comment: Generally when you have a dropdown, it is an overlay of sorts. You do not want it to push other content down, or expand the div that contains it. They are rendered as `position: absolute` and the parent left as `overflow: visible`. It then just covers whatever is behind it. Does this sound ideal? You may still run into issues with it going over the bottom of the window however. Solution many times is to pop-up instead of pop-down. Otherwise you will just have to manually in js detect this case and set the scroll position of the window/div.

Comment: div{
  overflow: auto;
}